# why in reverse function it work normal without using for loop for next character like ( sPtr[ count]( sPtr[ 2],if ( sPtr[ 3]...... and so on

Tags: c, string

```
     #include <stdio.h>

     void reverse( char sPtr[] ); /* prototype */

     int main( void )
      {  
       char sentence[ 80 ]; /* create char array */

       printf( "Enter a line of text:\n" );

      /* use fgets to read line of text */
      fgets( sentence, 80, stdin ); 

      printf( "\nThe line printed backward is:\n" );
      reverse( sentence );
      // system("pause");
      return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
      } /* end main */

       /* recursively outputs characters in string in reverse order */
        void reverse( char sPtr[])
      {  
         /* if end of the string */
         if ( sPtr[ 0 ] == '\0' )
         { /* base case */
           return; 
         } /* end if */ 
          else 
          {
              /* if not end of the string */ 
             reverse( &sPtr[ 1 ] ); /* recursion step */
              putchar( sPtr[ 0 ] ); /* use putchar to display character */
          } /* end else */
           }  /* end function reverse */
```

this code to print string and its reverse like
   james 
   semaj
   but i cannot figure out why when passing ptr to array it could print whole        string without for loop to make pointer indicate to next char to print it

Comment: Is this your entire code?

Comment: yes, this whole code

Comment: And your problem is why it's able to reverse it without any use of loops? @WallaAhmed

Comment: i want to know how i can pass ptr to string to the function reverse , and it can print the whole string by knowing only char sPtr[0]

Comment: Please do not overlook that `fgets` might retain any newline at its end. So you could check the line ending with `< ' '`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reverse` function is what we call a "recursive" function.  It calls itself as part of its operation.

The key pieces are:

- `sPtr[1]` is the second character in the string, which means `&sPtr[1]` is a pointer to the string containing everything except the first character.
- Calling `reverse(&sPtr[1])` has the effect of doing whatever `reverse` does on a string containing everything except the first character.
- calling `reverse` on an empty string prints nothing.

Recursive functions can be tricky to understand.  I would consider this to be a bad example to learn from because the iterative approach (with a `for` loop) is so easy to understand and this version is so cryptic.  There are other algorithms which are much more natural looking in recursive form.

Comment: &sPtr[1] is a pointer to the string containing everything except the first character. ,,,,,,, or is point to first char of  string ??

Comment: Both, actually.  C defines a string to be a contiguous series of bytes with a null character at the end.  If you point to a character within that string, that pointer also technically points at a string starting with that character.  It's a pointer to a character because that's what `char*`s do (by definition).  It's a pointer to a string because you and I know, from looking at the code, that that character happens to be part of a null-terminated array of characters.

Comment: void reverse( char sPtr[])
      {  
     int count=0;
         /* if end of the string */
         while (sPtr[count]!= '\0' )
   {
   printf("%c",sPtr[79-count]); 
            count++;   
    
   }

Comment: i used another way ,,    it also didnot work with me,

Comment: That code describes a very different issue that arises.  While `sentence` is an array of 80 characters, we're not always using all of them.  `fgets` puts a null terminator right after the end of the sentence, which is often not exactly 80 characters long.  Your code is actually reading the "garbage" at the end of `sentence` occurring after the null terminator put in place by `fgets`.  Use a function like `strlen` to get the length of the string, and use that length minus one instead of `79` and things should work better!  (also make sure you are checking the same character you are printing)

Comment: Your code checks `sPtr[count]` to see if it is null, but prints `sPtr[79-count]`.  That's probably not what you intended.